# I am trying to connect to an SMB share via Docker Compose and it will not give write permissions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, smb, cifs

I am new to docker. I am attempting run a docker server on a raspberry pi and have the volumes point to a network share so I can avoid persistent files directly on the pi. I am using docker compose and am attempting to mount an SMB share from my Unraid server to the docker containers utilizing volumes.

This is how I have tried mounting the SMB shares:

```
volumes:
  downloads:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=COOLUSERNAMEHERE,password=SUPERSECRETPASSWORD,vers=3
      device: //192.168.0.110/downloads
```

I then mount this volume inside the container as follows:

```
services:
  myservicename:
    image: theplaceigetmyimagefrom
    container_name: myservice
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Toronto
    volumes:
      - downloads:/downloads     
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This volume mounts just fine however it mounts as read only. No matter what I do I cannot get it to have write permissions. I again am new to docker. So I am probably trying the wrong stuff. I have tried adding `privileged: true` to the container but that didn't change anything. The SMB share I am connecting to is set to public and shared so there shouldn't be any user issues, however I have also logged in with a user that has "read/write"access to that folder as setup in Unraid itself.

Any ideas on next steps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I changed the version to 3.0 (not sure if that did anything at all) and I added GID and UID and the rw option:

```
volumes:
  downloads:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=COOLUSERNAMEHERE,password=SUPERSECRETPASSWORD,uid=1000,gid-1000,vers=3.0,rw
      device: //192.168.0.110/downloads
```

it now connects as expected.